# How to get the user_id created in Database using PHP?

Tags: php, android, sql, authentication, userid

I try to use SESSION or without. Maybe I have a issues using SESSION.
In phpMyAdmin I am using `userid int(11) auto_increment`.

All what created using POST method work.

```
<?php
session_start();    
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql11.000webhost.com", "a7083778_user",      "abcd12734", "a70830778_data");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $age ,$username, $password, $userPoints);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  
$_SESSION["userid"] = $userID;
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;
$response["userID"] = $_SESSiON["userid"]; 
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["age"] = $age;
    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["password"] = $password;
$response["userPoints"] = $userPoints;
}

echo json_encode($response);
 ?>
```

Comment: you want a unique id ? question is quite unclear

Comment: @Shubhank   sori it is my first question , Yes i need the unique id (created in Database ,where I can use auto_incrementation ) to create in Android app QR-code  unique for each  user

Comment: Please note that unhashed/plaintext passwords are considered poor security practice. You should be hashing them with an appropriate strong algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,i think it will work for you

```html
<?php
session_start();    
$conn = new mysqli("mysql11.000webhost.com", "a7083098_user", "abcd1234", "a7083098_data");
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$qry = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = $username AND password = $password";
$result =  $conn->query($qry);
$response = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
 $response["success"] = true;
 $response["userID"] = $row['userId'];
 $_SESSiON["userid"] = $response["userID"];   //Store userId in session
 $response["name"] = $row['name'];
 $response["age"] = $row['age'];
 $response["username"] = $row['username'];
 $response["password"] = $row['password'];
 $response["userPoints"] = $row['userPoints'];
}
echo json_encode($response);
session_destroy();

?>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment , but i have a problem                                          Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/a7083098/public_html/Login.php on line 9

Comment: Sir if you enter wrong username and password,then this error will come.

Comment: Because if no any data fetch from database,then $result->fetch_assoc() will display this error.

Comment: sori but this doesn't work :( ,  i can't even get login in . It is a Android app.

Comment: username and password you entered,exist in database or not,please check sir

Comment: $qry = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");        please remove ) from query

Comment: Sorry i forgot to remove ) bracket,i have made some changes in this code. Please use this code

Comment: Sorry i forgot to remove ) bracket,i have made some changes so please again copy paste the code and try again.

Comment: Yes login and password exist in th database

Comment: Everything is working !!! Thanks, I tried to resolve this problem about 3 days

Comment: Sorry only last question , in yours PHP code username can be String variable ( because now I can log in only if username is int if String doesnt work )